# Why are certain unicode characters not showing in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, unicode, interface-builder

I would like to include some nice unicode characters in a label. They are correctly displayed both in the code editor (which uses a Menlo font) and in the Utilities part (the right part of the screen) of Interface Builder. However, they are shown as a question mark both in the view in IB's canvas and in the app.

[image]

In the first picture you can see that the unicode character called "N-ary circled times operator" (Codepoint: 0x2A02) is shown correctly in the code editor.

[image]

In the second picture you can see a snapshot of IB, where the character is shown correctly in the textfield on the right, but not in the view. (The font in the picture is System 17.0, but the issue remains with all the other fonts.)

It looks like the rendering used in the view is that of an older browser (actually, for some other unicode symbols, the character shown in the view is a more colorful variant of the character you see in the code editor).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: To enter special character. In Xcode menu, choose **Edit > Emoji & Characters** and pick your symbol. However, I can't find your symbol in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the fonts that are provided with iOS include a glyph for that character. If you visit [this test page](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2A02) in MobileSafari, you will also see it rendered as a fallback square.

In order to have this character rendered correctly, you will need to supply a font with your application that includes a glyph for it.

Comment: So, are you saying that the Menlo font used in the code editor, which displays the glyph correctly, and the Menlo font family that you can select in IB (which doesn't display it correctly) are two different things?

Comment: Menlo doesn't contain a glyph for it either. The Xcode editor (like most applications) will automatically try to fallback to another font on your system that does---probably the [Apple Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Symbols) font in this case.

Comment: Thanks! It may be useful to know that, as soon as I added the "Apple Symbols.ttc" file to my app, the symbol started to show correctly in IB, even if the selected font was "System" (but then it didn't show in the app). When I also set "Apple Symbols" as the label's font, then the glyph looked all right in the app, too.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article by Marcin](https://www.figma.com/blog/when-fonts-fall/) to be insightful. The article talks about how behind the scenes, system fonts are used as a fallback to render characters not available in the user-specified font.

> It turns out that after you’re done with your font fallback list, your browser or operating system quietly adds over a dozen more fonts to help you out, including some fonts created expressly just for this purpose.
>
> ...
>
> As an example, the four-font list on my Mac gets quietly extended to look more like this:
>
> > font-family: ***Joanna**, **Helvetica Now**, **Helvetica**, **Arial**, Menlo, Monaco, .AppleSymbolsFB, LucidaGrande, CourierNewPSMT, GeezaPro, NotoNastaliqUrdu, Ayuthaya, Kailasa, PingFangSC, PingFangTC, HiraginoSans-W3, HiraginoSansGB-W3, PingFangHK, AppleSDGothicNeo, KohinoorBangla, KohinoorDevanagari, KohinoorGujarati, MuktaMahee, NotoSansKannada, KhmerSangamMN, LaoSangamMN, MalayalamSangamMN, NotoSansMyanmar, NotoSansZawgyi, NotoSansOriya, SinhalaSangamMN, TamilSangamMN, KohinoorTelugu, NotoSansArmenian, EuphemiaUCAS, STIXGeneral, Galvji, Kefa, .NotoSansUniversal, AppleColorEmoji, .LastResort;*

For mobile, I have a feeling that the system fallback fonts are not as many as their desktop counterparts. I would *speculate* that this is due to the need to be stored on mobile devices with relatively lower memory. I would expect as large memory on mobile devices becomes more common place, that system fallback fonts with larger unicode support will be included in mobile operating systems like iOS and Android.